# How to get the value of a dropdown using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown menu and a link in a table. What I want is to get the value of the dropdown menu that is being retrieve in a row.

```
    <td><?php echo form_dropdown('status',array('Fine' => 'Fine', 'Disposable' => 'Disposable'),'','class="status" id="status"'); ?></td>
    <td align="center">             
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-small"><i class="icon-edit icon-large"></i></a>
    <div id="return"  style="float: left;"> 
    <!--when this one is clicked I can get the value of the dropdown-->
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-small return"><i class="icon-backward icon-large"></i></a>
    </div>
```

[image]

How can I get the value of the dropdown When the link with the class of `return` is clicked? I've tried `.closest()` function but it returned `undefined`. Thanks!

Comment: What's the rendered html look like/

Comment: See the image as shown

Comment: The image as shown doesn't show us HTML. We need to see specifics, can't write code based off the image.

Comment: Just "View Source" and copy that section of the HTML. Very easy.

Comment: Can it be that php is making 2 different selects with the same ID? that will give you many problems, and is invalid HTML!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried?

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.return', function() {
   alert($(this).closest('tr').find('#status').val());
});
```

**Note:** Using elements with the same `id` is a bad practice and can give you problems along the road. Please consider to remove #status id from the elements and use a class when selecting the element.

Try this instead:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.return', function() {
   alert($(this).closest('tr').find('select.status').val());
});
```

Comment: That works great. I just forgot to add `find()` big thanks!

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza I'm glad it helped you. Don't forget to upvote the answer if it was useful

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
$(".return").click(function({
   selectedValue = $('select[name="status"]').val(); //using name tag
   selectedValue = $('.status').val(); // using Class 
   selectedValue = $('#status').val(); // using Id
   console.log(selectedValue);
}));
```